# Ruby how to extract element value from a data structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]x =    {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxx=",
     "file"=>#>,
     "unit_id"=>"00001"}

I have ruby data structure like this and um trying to get the value of @original_filename field

I tried something like this

```
x["@original_filename"]
```

and

```
x[:original_filename]
```

But both has thrown me an error . How to access that specified element value?

Comment: The key `"@original_filename"`is not present...

Comment: I think he is getting the file `ActionDispatch` parameters

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile/original_filename

Comment: may be get some help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631056/where-from-does-paperclip-get-the-name-of-original-file

Comment: There s something wrong with the way its display let me upload a screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter ["file"] is a ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile, which has the original_filename member variable, as you can see in the params displayed in your image or here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html

So, the way to get this value would be `x["file"].original_filename`

Answer (score 2):

looks like you're trying to upload a file; from your tiny screenshot maybe you're referring to `params[:file].original_filename`?

Comment: let me try it  thank you

Comment: um getting this error undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass